# Visualization of TreeMap and LinkedHashMap in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, treemap, linkedhashmap

I am trying to understand how these data structures actually are visualized. It is said that `TreeMap` puts the entries in *natural order* [of keys] and `LinkedHashMap` puts entries in the *order* in which they are inserted.

My question is, does the *iteration* over each of these data structures mean traversing over **all** the elements spread over all the buckets (or inner array)?

My understanding was that, for instance, in case of `TreeMap`, elements with an identical *hashcode* are placed in a *Tree* structure [of some sort]. Therefore, if a `TreeMap` has elements in **6** out of 16 indexes [in its bucket array], it would contain **6** `Tree`'s -- one for each.

Similarly, in case of `LinkedHashMap` (which should have been called *DoublyLinkedHashMap* in reality), each bucket would have a doubly linked list of its own.

So, how does *iteration* actually take place? Does it happen over **all** the elements in all the buckets or only over elements of a single bucket? Am I wrong in my assumption?

P.S. And it seems like in *Java 8*, `HashMap` implementation uses a `Tree` or `LinkedList` depending on the number of elements for each bucket containing more than 8 or less than 6 elements, respectively!

Comment: I don't know where you got your idea of how these data structures work, but it doesn't bear much resemblance to reality. For example, `TreeMap` doesn't have buckets and doesn't use hashes at all.

Comment: Ok. You are suggesting `TreeMap` is simply a [binary/rad-black] tree data structure. Where does the _hash_ part come in the play then?

Comment: It doesn't. If it did, `TreeMap` would have `Hash` in the name.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I guess I got confused with the new implementation of `HashMap` in _Java 8_, where it seems like, the data structure could have a mixture of trees and linkedlists in each bucket depending on the number of elements, and thought `TreeMap` uses some sort of hashing for its mapping.

Comment: @user2357112 Forgot to ask, given my misunderstanding of `TreeMap`, I wanted to get clarification on `LinkedHashMap`, that it is, indeed, a `HashMap` that uses _Doubly Linked List_ instead of _Linked List_ to place elements in each bucket, correct?

Comment: The linked list in a `LinkedHashMap` is completely unrelated to the collision-handling linked list in each bucket. It's a separate linked list that just keeps track of insertion order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for the normal implementations is in the src.zip file that comes with the Oracle JDK installs.

`TreeMap`: As indicated in its documentation, it is a Red-Black tree. The critical code for simple forwards iteration over the keys is the method `static <K,V> TreeMap.Entry<K,V> successor(Entry<K,V> t)`. It recursively scans the tree, in the order left-parent-right. It depends for ordering on nodes being inserted in the tree according to their key order.

`LinkedHashMap`: It has a doubly linked list in arrival order imposed on top of a hash structure with buckets. The nested class `Entry` extends `HashMap.Node` to add `before` and `after` references. Normal forwards iteration follows the `after` chain.

Answer (score 0):

To complement [@patricia-shanahan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30784709/4805778)'s answer:

To add a visualization to `LinkedHashMap` (this is for **Java 7** and older as **Java 8** is different), assuming the elements were added in order of `A`, `B`, ..., `E` (and assuming `A` has a hashcode that makes it fall in bucket 0 or `D` has a hashcode that places in bucket 3), a `HashMap` with 4 bins would have the following layout ("**|**" represents next property variable in `HashMap.Entry<K, V>` in the bucket linked list):

```
║ 0 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 
╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬
║ A ║   ║ B ║ D ║
╠═|═╬═══╬═|═╬═|═╬
║ E ║   ║ C ║nul║
╠═|═╬═══╬═|═╬═══╬
║nul║   ║nul║   ║    
╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬
```

In addition, each of the elements, `A`...`E`, would have two additional references (`LinkedHashMap.Entry<K, V>` of after and before):

```
A---->B---->C---->D---->E      
^____|^____|^____|^____|
```

So in total, each `LinkedHashMap.Entry<K, V>` would have 3 references: `next`, `after`, and `before`. Therefore, there is a single element, i.e. `A` (of type `LinkedHashMap.Entry<K, V>`), with three references. `TreeMap` has also three references but they reference other `TreeMap.Entry<K, V>`'s differently for different purpose: `parent`, `left`, and `right`.